# WiX: No InstallUISequence table being created in MSI

Tags: wix

I have a WiX file that includes this snippet:

```
<CustomAction Id="DownloadCache" FileKey="CACHEDOWNLOADER.EXE" ExeCommand="/v" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore"/>
<UI>
    <Dialog Id="ExitDialog" Title="Product Installer" Height="60" Width="250">
        ...

    </Dialog>
    <Dialog Id="FatalErrorDialog" Title="Product Installer" Height="60" Width="250">
        ...
    </Dialog>
    <TextStyle Id="DefaultFont" FaceName="Arial" Size="10" />
    <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="DefaultFont" />
    <InstallUISequence>
        <Custom Action="DownloadCache" After="ExecuteAction">(NOT Installed) AND (Not REMOVE)</Custom>
        <Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success" />
        <Show Dialog="FatalErrorDialog" OnExit="error" />
    </InstallUISequence>
</UI>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="DownloadCache" After="WriteRegistryValues">(NOT Installed) AND (Not REMOVE)</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The issue is, the resulting .MSI does NOT contain an InstallUISequence table.

I went through the tutorial *[Events and Actions](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson3.php)* and the above seems correct. I'm definitely missing something here. How can I fix it?

Comment: Hey Christopher, I didn't mean that! I went back to that question yesterday and didn't see your answer being posted, but now that you reminded me I just did it, I was going too anyway! Again, sorry about that, you really did help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be more than meets the eye here. Even the simplest fragment below will generate an `InstallUISequence` table with the bare minimum actions of ValidateProductID, CostInitialize, FileCost, CostFinalize and ExecuteAction. No actual UI elements *[per se](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/per_se#Adverb)*, but that's another issue.... ([Are Dialogs Optional Now??](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2007/04/are-dialogs-optional-now.html))

```
<Wix...>
    <Product...>
        <Package.../>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Definitely, it's a big project with some includes... I'm suspecting on some element explicitly removing that table before my wix gets compiled.

Comment: Well the only way I know how to do this is to author a InstallUISequence Element followed by a <StandardAction Suppress="yes"/>   for each of the actions that I mentioned and then turn off Windows Installer validation to ignore the error messages from WiX.  I think you'd really have to go out of your way to do this.